# Controlling database polling in Quartz.NET

Tags: quartz.net

I'm using the Quartz.NET scheduler with the AdoJobStore. I know that the scheduler will keep on polling the tables for jobs and triggers. How I can control the polling frequency through configuration?

Answer (score 4):

I've checked the code and it seems that this is the property:

```
quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime
```

and this is an explanation I've [found](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigMain.html):

> **org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime**
>
> Is the amount of time in milliseconds that the scheduler will
> wait before re-queries for available
> triggers when the scheduler is
> otherwise idle. Normally you should
> not have to 'tune' this parameter,
> unless you're using XA transactions,
> and are having problems with delayed
> firings of triggers that should fire
> immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Definitely mark as answer if it works.

Comment: @Mark: Any news with this problem?

Comment: This is an old thread, but I tried the setting and dialed it up to 10 second intervals (10,000) and polling continues in ~3 second intervals.

Comment: The link is broken.  Here is another link:  http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigMain.html

Comment: @TravisSchneeberger: Many thanks. I've fixed it. Cheers.